# I can't see lamps or selection outlines or anything "orange" in 3D view anymore

Tags: 3d-view, light, selection-tools

I am very new to Blender and I have no idea what I could have done to cause something like this. I remember messing with the CPU and GPU rendering options. I tried downloading other files from Blender Cloud, and they didn't have the issue. I copied the User Preferences but it's still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing, that can make lamps and outlines disappear is "Only Render" Display option in right panel (the one that appears and disappears when you press N )[image]

Comment: That solved it! Thank you soooo much for the fast response! :D